# Can I provide a custom FileLocker for a FileWritingMessageHandler?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, distributed-lock

I am using a `FileReadingMessageSource` with a custom `FileLocker`:

```java
@Component
public class JdbcFileLocker implements FileLocker {
...
```

```java
@Autowired
JdbcFileLocker jdbcFileLocker;

@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(value = "fileInputChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "1000"))
public MessageSource<File> fileReadingMessageSource() {
    FileReadingMessageSource source = new FileReadingMessageSource();
    source.setDirectory(new File("/workspace/in"));
    source.setFilter(new SimplePatternFileListFilter("input"));
    source.getScanner().setLocker(jdbcFileLocker);
    return source;
}
```

Now I want to use the `FileLocker jdbcFileLocker` to unlock the file after handling it in the `FileWritingMessageHandler`:

```java
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "fileInputChannel")
  public MessageHandler fileWritingMessageHandler() {
    FileWritingMessageHandler fileWritingMessageHandler = 
      new FileWritingMessageHandler(new File("/workspace/out"));
```

Do I have to unlock the file in my own `@ServiceActivator` or can I give my `FileLocker` somehow to the FileWritingMessageHandler?

---

EDIT: Adding an `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice`

```java
@Bean
ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice unlockAdvice() {
  ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice advice = 
    new ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice();
  advice.setSuccessChannel(unlockChannel);
  return advice;
}
```

So I can add this `Advice` to my `FileWritingMessageHandler`:

```java
@Autowired
ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice unlockAdvice;

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "fileInputChannel")
public MessageHandler fileWritingMessageHandler() {
  FileWritingMessageHandler handler = 
    new FileWritingMessageHandler(new File("/workspace/out"));
  handler.setFileExistsMode(FileExistsMode.REPLACE);
  handler.setDeleteSourceFiles(true);
  handler.setExpectReply(false);
  handler.setFileNameGenerator(message -> "output");
  handler.setAdviceChain(List.of(unlockAdvice));
  return handler;
}
```

The unlocking is then handled by a `@ServiceActivator` listening to the `unlockChannel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all consider to use `fileWritingMessageHandler.setExpectReply(false)`. Since by default a `FileWritingMessageHandler` behaves as a gateway and is going to try to produce a reply which is not handled in your flow and therefore some error is going to be thrown to your poller.

For your `FileLocker` use-case see an `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` on your `fileWritingMessageHandler` service activator. Its `onSuccessExpression` could do an unlocking which is really going to be done after the `FileWritingMessageHandler` finishes its process. See docs for more info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#message-handler-advice-chain

Another is to have a `fileInputChannel` as a `PublishSubscribeChannel` without changing a configuration for the current `fileWritingMessageHandler`. But you add another service activator subscriber to that channel which is going to perform `FileLocker.unlock()` logic. To ensure that second subscriber is called after the first, consider to add an `@Order(100)` for your unlocker service activator. Also see docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#channel-implementations-publishsubscribechannel

Comment: Thank you very much! I opted for the `Advice` solution (Visible in the EDIT above :-)